# Is it possible to use singleton with ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift2, singleton

I was trying to use singleton but with no luck of getting the same instance

I used it this way...

```
class RCHDownloadTVCC: UITableViewController {
private static let sharedInstance = RCHDownloadTVCC()

static func defaultInstance() -> RCHDownloadTVCC {
return sharedInstance
}
......}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view controller should never be a singleton. Absolutely never.

View controllers are created as needed and destroyed when not needed anymore. Singletons are created when needed the first time, and never destroyed.

Making a viewcontroller a singleton would stop viewDidLoad from working properly, for example. Apart from that, you never know that the same view controller won't be needed twice.

Comment: I am making a download manager if it is not good way to use a singleton then how would I add a new download to my view controller without having access to it ?

Comment: @Raffi perform downloads in shared single data model object. When you need to display downloads - compose them in new view controller instance. Learn MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class RCHDownloadTVCC: UITableViewController {
static let sharedInstance = RCHDownloadTVCC()
......}
```

Get it in some other class:

```
let rchdownloadSingletone = RCHDownloadTVCC.sharedInstance
```

**Upd:** Ofc you need to be sure that you only initialize `RCHDownloadTVCC` class by `sharedInstance` property. Any other way to initialize it (for example, from storyboard) will return new instance. And I think that define view controller as singleton is bad style coding

Comment: I can see what is happening now I am using storyboard so it will be for sure a different instance, thanks for reminding me